# How do I open a modal using bootstrap in angular?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a simple chat room web app. I am trying to bootstrap a modal to angular to include a create new room button. I followed the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and followed the sample code but when I tried to run it, the modal would not open. What am I missing? Here is the template and controller.

```js
(function() {
    function ModalCtrl($uibModal, Room) {
        //this.newRoom = Room.addRoom();
        
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/modal.html',
            controller: 'ModalCtrl as $modal'
        })
    }
    
    angular
        .module('blocChat')
        .controller('ModalCtrl', ['Room', ModalCtrl]);
})();
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Create new room</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>modal body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$modal.open()">New Room</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
(function() {
    function ModalCtrl($uibModal, Room) {
        //this.newRoom = Room.addRoom();

        $scope.open=function(){
          angular.element('#myModal').modal('show');

        };
    }

    angular
        .module('blocChat')
        .controller('ModalCtrl', ['Room', ModalCtrl]);
})();
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Create new room</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>modal body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="open()">New Room</button>
```

Comment: still does not open. I am wondering if it has to do with the script dependencies but the console does not present any errors

Comment: can u try removing outer function (){} ..?

Comment: function ModalCtrl($uibModal, Room) { //this.newRoom = Room.addRoom(); $scope.open=function(){ angular.element('#myModal').mo dal('show'); }; } angular .module('blocChat') .controller('ModalCtrl', ['Room', ModalCtrl]);

Comment: It is still not working. And the modal button will only appear if I place the button tag in my home template. It does not appear with this current set up.

Answer (score 0):

`$uibModal` dependency needs to be injected into `ModalCtrl` controller, like this:

```
angular
    .module('blocChat')        
    .controller('ModalCtrl', ['$uibModal', 'Room', ModalCtrl]);
```

where

```
function ModalCtrl($uibModal, Room) {
   //...
}
```

**Example**

```js
(function () {
    function ModalCtrl($uibModal, Room) {
        var $modal = this;
        //this.newRoom = Room.addRoom();

        $modal.open = function () {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/templates/modal.html',
                controller: 'ModalCtrl as $modal'
            });
        };


    }

    angular
        .module('blocChat', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
        .factory('Room', function () {
            return {
                addRoom: function () {
                    console.log('add room');
                }
            };
        })
        .controller('ModalCtrl', ['$uibModal', 'Room', ModalCtrl]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.4.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="blocChat" ng-controller="ModalCtrl as $modal">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="app/templates/modal.html">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
           <h3 class="modal-title">Create new room</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <p>modal body</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$modal.open()">New Room</button>

</div>
```